# Twisted web server: execute a deferred action after sending response

Tags: python, twisted

I have a simple web service defined as:

```
from twisted.internet import endpoints
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import resource
from twisted.web import server

class TestService(resource.Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "ok"

ts = TestService()
endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:{}".format(8080)).listen(server.Site(ts))
reactor.run()
```

This service always sends *ok* on every GET request.

Fine.

But I need to execute a deferred action 1 minute after the request has been processed.

How do I do it?

I mean something like this:

```
from twisted.internet import endpoints
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import resource
from twisted.web import server

def deferred_action():
    time.sleep(60)
    # do some action...
    print("action completed")

class TestService(resource.Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        defer(deferred_action) # how do I do this?
        return "ok"

ts = TestService()
endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:{}".format(8080)).listen(server.Site(ts))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: `reactor.callLater(60.0, deferred_action)`

Comment: This is it! So simple! It can be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `callLater()` method of the reactor:

```
reactor.callLater(60.0, deferred_action)
```

You can also add more arguments which would then be passed into the `deferred_action` function. Of course it will need to accept them.

```
def deferred_action(value):
    print(value)

class TestService(resource.Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        reactor.callLater(60.0, deferred_action, 'some value')
```